# Prevent selected item from going out of view in QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

I am using a QListView with only single selection and selection changes handled by the up and down arrows. Everything is working as expected with one minor issue. If many items are added to the top of the list then the currently selected item risks moving down and out of view. Is there any way to detect when this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, but first of all I try to do dimilar thing, I run timer and every 2 second I insert new row to the begin of list and try to detect, is selected item still visible?

```
//somewhere in the constructor, it is not important
 ListModel = new QStandardItemModel();
ui->listView->setModel(ListModel);
```

Now when I want to insert new row , I wrote code, which checks is the item visible

```
    QStandardItem* Items = new QStandardItem(QString::number(qrand()%100));
    ListModel->insertRow(0,Items);
// here we get rect of current selected item
    QRect rec = ui->listView->visualRect(ui->listView->currentIndex());

//here we get all listView region, convert it to rect and check is our listView 
//contain selected item
if(ui->listView->viewport()->visibleRegion().boundingRect().contains(rec))
{
    qDebug() << "visible";//all good
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "not visible";//not good, we need do something
    //you want to detect it, so you get!
    //now you know that item "runs away from you"
    //and you can do some actions
    someAction();
}
```

I test it on my computer, when I can see item, I get visible word, when item tries "run away from me" I get not visible

I hope it helps.